# How do I get python to recognize that there has been no input

Tags: python, input, enter

I would like to create a program in which if the user presses the enter key without typing in anything, python would recognize the lack of input and relocate it to the appropriate actions. For example:

```
some = int(input("Enter a number"))

if not some:
    print("You didn't enter a number")

else:
    print("Good job")
```

What I would like to happen is if the user pressed the enter key without typing a value, they would receive the first statement. However, currently I only receive an error. Thank you.

Edit: I've had various responses about putting a try catch statement. Actually, in my original code I had a error handling statement for a ValueError. However I would like to distinguish between the user entering words instead of numbers and the user not entering anything. Is this possible?

Comment: can it be: `if some is not None:` instead of `if not some:`

Comment: Still getting the error, unfortunately

Comment: Much confusion could have been saved below if this question had been tagged python3. Please do so in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for

```
try:
    some = int(input("Enter a number"))
    print("Good job")
except (SyntaxError, ValueError):
    print("You didn't enter a number")
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting this error because anything given to `input` is expected to be a valid Python expression, but entering nothing gives

```
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

**Edit: In Python 3.x, input is fine - the error will only be the ValueError below.**

You can remedy this problem by switching from `input` to `raw_input`, but `int` also can't parse an empty string, which results in another error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

So, you can either catch the exception that is produced, or check for empty input with a conditional statement. The latter is preferable, since other errors that may occur in your code may be swallowed up with exception handling.

```
raw = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
if not raw:
    print "You didn't enter a number"
else:
    some = int(raw)
    print "Good job"
```

Note of course that you will probably still have to deal with other syntax issues, such as if a person inputs something that isn't an integer (e.g. "cat")

Comment: Is there any way to distinguish between this error and a regular ValueError? Because in my original program, I had a try, exception statement that would print an error statement when the user entered a word instead of a number. However, I want to provide a different statement if they don't enter anything. Also, because I'm using Python 3, would the raw_input still apply?

Comment: The generic error when `int` reaches something it can't handle is a `ValueError`, and trying to differentiate between specific types of errors is possible, but unnecessarily hard. Use conditional statements to match the input string with any expected cases you want to cover; i.e. if the string is empty, or if it does not contain a number, if it's a float, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I searched and found a similar case in the official python documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html):

```
while True:
    try:
        x = int(raw_input("Please enter a number: "))
        print "good job"
        break
    except ValueError:
        print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

#### update 01

code updated as below:

```
while True:
    try:
        x = raw_input("Please enter a number: ")
        x_mod = int(x)
        print "good job"
        break
    except ValueError:
        if len(x)==0:
            print "you entered nothing"
        else:
            print "Oops!  That was no valid number.  Try again..."
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `raw_input` and then a `try-catch` to type check your input.

```
data = raw_input('Enter number: ')
try:
    print('You gave me the number: %i' % int(data))
except:
    print("I need a number")
```

Answer (score 0):

@user3495234 You may have solved this but I would solve this in following way.

```
import re

some = input("Enter a number?\n>")
reg = re.compile('^[+-]?(\d+\.\d+|\d+\.|\.\d+|\d+)([eE][+-]?\d+)?$')  
# A regexp from the perldoc perlretut

if some == "":
    print("Please enter something.")
elif reg.match(some):
    x = float(some)  # To avoid type casting error
    y = int(x)  # Apparently int(float) = int
    print("Good job")
    print(y)  # Checking for value is integer or not.
else:
    print("Looks like you didn't enter a number.")
```

I tried using **isdigit()** method to distinguish between the user entering words instead of numbers but that doesn't work well with float. [See this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138202/using-isdigit-for-floats)

Updated regular expression to [perldoc perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Building-a-regexp) one because previous one was giving error in some cases.

Comment: If there is anything that I can do to improve my answer let me know.