# How to check if a string represents a float number

Tags: python, decimal

I'm using this to check if a variable is numeric, I also want to check whether it's a floating point number.

```
if(width.isnumeric() == 1)
```

Comment: Would you want `3` and `3.5` to go in the same check?

Comment: `isinstance(width, type(1.0))` works in python 2.7

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a number is int or float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541155/check-if-a-number-is-int-or-float)

Comment: @JGreenwell: `width.isnumeric()` is a hint that `width` is a string.  He is not checking to see if a real number is a float; he is checking to see if a *string* could be converted to a float.

Comment: @zondo why would that be a hint? I've used varying values of width (from float to int) for a number of projects I've developed - besides [at least one of the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4541155/check-if-a-number-is-int-or-float/4541207#4541207) is fine for checking a string

Comment: @JGreenwell If `width` is a float, `width.isnumeric` doesn't exist.  `isnumeric` is a string method.

Comment: true, but that question includes answers for checking both int types and str types so it still a good fit - though not exact and answers here are good too (so more a related/linked at this point anyway).

Comment: Your question is not at all clear --- note all the comments trying to guess what your inputs (and input types) are, what outputs you want, and how you intend to handle edge cases.  **These are all things that _you_ should tell _us_**, not things we should be guessing at.  What _exactly_ are you trying to do, and _why_?  What kinds of inputs do you expect?  What outputs do you want from those inputs?  What do you mean by "floating point number"?  `1.0` is of type `float`, but it has an integer value (as does `fractions.Fraction(10, 5)`) --- are these "floating point" for your purposes, or not?

Comment: @zondo  While I agree that Harry Krek probably intended `width` to be a string, it's really not our job to play "guess the spec" with questions like this.  If the question is this unclear to people who have already found it, it will be of _zero_ use to later visitors who are searching for answers to the same question (whatever it turns out to be) --- they'll never find it.

Answer (score 17):

The easiest way is to convert the string to a float with `float()`:

```
>>> float('42.666')
42.666
```

If it can't be converted to a float, you get a `ValueError`:

```
>>> float('Not a float')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Not a float'
```

Using a `try`/`except` block is typically considered the best way to handle this:

```
try:
  width = float(width)
except ValueError:
  print('Width is not a number')
```

Note you can also use `is_integer()` on a `float()` to check if it's an integer:

```
>>> float('42.666').is_integer()
False
>>> float('42').is_integer()
True
```

Comment: add a try/except ... but yeah this is the most right answer imho :)

Comment: Using `is_integer()` to distinguish ints from floats is a nice touch.

Answer (score 7):

```
def is_float(string):
  try:
    return float(string) and '.' in string  # True if string is a number contains a dot
  except ValueError:  # String is not a number
    return False
```

Output:

```
>> is_float('string')
>> False
>> is_float('2')
>> False
>> is_float('2.0')
>> True
>> is_float('2.5')
>> True
```

Comment: not so good, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379906/parse-string-to-float-or-int

Answer (score 0):

Here another solution without "try" and which is returning a truth-value directly. Thanks to @Cam Jackson. I found this solution here: [Using isdigit for floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138202/using-isdigit-for-floats)

The idea is to remove exactly 1 decimal point before using isdigit():

```
>>> "124".replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()
True
>>> "12.4".replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()
True
>>> "12..4".replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()
False
>>> "192.168.1.1".replace(".", "", 1).isdigit()
False
```