# How to validate floating numbers in isdigit() in python

Tags: python

I am trying to validate a user input, and the user input is required to be positive integers including floating point numbers. I tried with isdigit(), it validated all the non-numeric inputs and negative integers as well but could not validate the floating point numbers.
Below is my code

```
 def is_number(s):
     while (s.isdigit() == False):
       s = input("Enter only numbers, not less than 0 : ")
 return float(s)
```

#method call

```
 while('true'):
      membershipFee = is_number(input('Enter the base membership fee, or zero to quit: '))
```

Comment: Should a floating point number return `float` or `int`. If `int` should it always round down?

Comment: ohh thanks for pointing out, that should be float ..cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can try the conversion and catch any errors. If python's happy, you're happy.

```
def is_number(s):
    while True:
        try:
            retval = float(s)
            if s >= 0.:
                return s
        except ValueError:
            pass
        s = input("Enter only numbers, not less than 0 : ")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use isdigit(), you can't use it on a float. One possible solution is to use a regex to validate your floats.

[Using isdigit for floats?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138202/using-isdigit-for-floats)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
#check if there is only one decimal place and check if it is not negative
s = input('Enter the number :')
if s.replace('.','',1).isdigit() and '-' not in s:
    print ('OK to process')
else:
    print ('not OK to process')
```

This will ensure that you will have the kind of numbers you need.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
def isNumber(f):
    return all([p.isdigit() for p in [f[:f.find('.')], f[f.find('.')+1:]] if len(p)])

print(isNumber('12.543'))
print(isNumber('185'))
print(isNumber('.2341'))
print(isNumber('163.'))
print(isNumber('14.356.67'))
```